# Why get "Mismatch between request payer account number and session" when use paypal smart button with multiple payee

Tags: express, vue.js, paypal

Is it possible to pay to multiple payee with using login informations or smart button?

I tried the following

```js
paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
              reference_id: 'reference1',
              amount: {
                value: 1,
                currency: 'USD',
                breakdown: {
                  item_total: {
                    currency_code: 'USD',
                    value: 1
                  }
                }
              },
              description: 'description',
              payee: {
                email_address: 'example2@email.com'
              },
              items: [{
                name: 'item1',
                unit_amount: {
                  currency_code: 'USD',
                  value: 1
                },
                quantity: 1
              }]
            },
            {
              reference_id: 'referenceid1',
              amount: {
                value: 1,
                currency: 'USD',
                breakdown: {
                  item_total: {
                    currency_code: 'USD',
                    value: 1
                  }
                }
              },
              description: 'The payment transaction description.',
              payee: {
                email_address: 'example2@email.com'
              },
              items: [{
                name: 'item2',
                unit_amount: {
                  currency_code: 'USD',
                  value: 1
                },
                quantity: 1
              }]
            }]
          })
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!')
          })
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container')
```

```html
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxx"></script>
```

and get error

```js
{
description: "Mismatch between request payer account number and session"
field: "/purchase_units/@reference_id==reference1"
issue: "PAYER_INVALID_FOR_PAYMENT"
}
```

with single purchase unit work correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible, only a single purchase_unit can be approved in the Checkout flow